# jQuery - If contains number between x and y

Tags: jquery, contains, addclass

I currently have a table that is populated with numbers via PHP. I want to use jQuery to check if a cell contains a number between lets say 1 and 10 and then apply a class to that cell.

This is what I have...

HTML - PHP populates numbers

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="times"> 11:00</td>
    <td class="number"> 10 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="times"> 12:00</td>
    <td class="number"> 15 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$( "td.number:contains('10')").addClass( "green" );
```

This works great but I need it to do a number between 2 numbers like >=5 && <=10.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter elements based on some condition.

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

When `true` is returned the element will be added to set and when `false` is returned the element will be removed from set.

**Live Demo**

```js
$('td.number').filter(function() {
  // Get the number and convert it to Number
  var num = +($(this).text().trim());

  return num >= 5 && num <= 10;
}).addClass('green');
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="times">11:00</td>
    <td class="number">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="times">12:00</td>
    <td class="number">15</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Tushar's is the correct answer for it operates on only those elements that need to be operated on.

I only added this approach for a case where there may be a need to add a class to **every `td.number`**, based on the value as show in the demo. **Or you may replace 'yellow' with '' and it would do the current job.**

```js
$('td.number').addClass(function() {
  var n = +this.textContent;
  return (n >= 1 && n <= 10) ? 'green' : 'yellow';
});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="times">11:00</td>
    <td class="number">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="times">12:00</td>
    <td class="number">15</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For `addClass` callback +1

Comment: how about `return (n >= 1 && n <= 10) ? 'green' : '';`? Only adding a class if the condition is true

Comment: @tushar, you're right. Good point.  That's what I originally had before I thought that the current version may be more useful, since it's dealing with the whole set.

Answer (score 0):

This works too [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqmure2e/)

```js
$("td.number").each(function() {
  var inner = $(this).text();
  if (!isNaN(inner) && 0 < inner && inner <= 10) {
    $(this).addClass('green');
  }
  // can add one or more "else if" statements for multi-stage comparison
  // like add more classes or filter out unneeded elements
});
```

```css
.green {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="times">11:00</td>
    <td class="number">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="times">12:00</td>
    <td class="number">15</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```